# How can I detect erroneous KeyEvent's?

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I have a fullscreen OpenGL Activity and I am trying to get input from the virtual keyboard.

I am not doing anything with the keyboard input yet, just logging it out, but I have noticed some very strange behavior.

If I just press a key, I get a key down, followed by a key up event with no flags and everyone is happy.

If I press and hold a key to get the alternate key, for example holding 'h' to get '&', I immedately get a key down and and key up for the 'h'.  When I let go, I get a key down for shift, key down for '&', key up for '&' and then key up for shift.

Five of those six events are exactly as expected.  The key up for the 'h' would make sense if `FLAG_CANCELED` was set, but `getFlags()` is returning zero and `isCanceled()` is returning false.  There doesn't seem to be anything in the key up event to indicate that the user hasn't actually let go of the key yet.

I am getting the same behavior with `onKeyUp` and `dispatchKeyEvent`.

I am also getting the same strange behavior if I immediately slide my finger from one key to another.  I get key down and key up for the original key and then key down and key up for the key I end the slide on and I can't figure out anything that would indicate the first key up should be ignored.

My test device is an HTC Evo 4G running Android 2.3.3 and I am building with API Level 9.

**Update:**

More weirdness... The backspace key sends a key down and key up when the keyboard is in alphabetic mode.  In symbol mode, it only sends key down.